# How to load XHR requests in Cordova relative to the base href?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am using AngularJS and I have something like:

```
myApp.config([
  '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$sceProvider', 'appConstants', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $sceProvider, appConstants) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: "/templates/login.html"
    }).state('tos', {
```

When this loads in Cordova, it tries to get it from `file:///templates/login.html` but really it should get it from `file:///Users/ssiddiqui/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5BFA4F09-2C0A-4916-9D08-21D8BDC9E0A8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/12B77264-BCB1-4DAA-B1FA-8BC4033ADFAC/HelloWorld.app/www/templates/login.html` since:

`<base href="file:///Users/ssiddiqui/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5BFA4F09-2C0A-4916-9D08-21D8BDC9E0A8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/12B77264-BCB1-4DAA-B1FA-8BC4033ADFAC/HelloWorld.app/www/">`

So how can I make this happen?

Comment: i do use httpInterceptor for this...

Comment: How do you propose to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the http-interceptor, specifically request-interceptor, you can tweak the url if it ends with .html

steps

1. get the hosting address

   ```
   var hostPath = document.location.pathname.substring(0, document.location.pathname.length - 1);`
   ```
2. change the url if it ends with .html

   ```
       if (config.url.indexOf(".html") !== -1) {
           config.url = hostPath + config.url;
       }
   ```

the complete request-interceptor looks like this

```
    var requestInterceptor = function (config) {
        var hostPath = document.location.pathname.substring(0, document.location.pathname.length - 1);
        if (config.url.indexOf(".html") !== -1) {
            config.url = hostPath + config.url;
        }
        return config || $q.when(config);
    };
```

**SETUP**

```
csapp.factory('MyHttpInterceptor', function ($q){
    var requestInterceptor = function (config) {
        var hostPath = document.location.pathname.substring(0, document.location.pathname.length - 1);
        if (config.url.indexOf(".html") !== -1) {
            config.url = hostPath + config.url;
        }
        return config || $q.when(config);
    };
    return {
       request: requestInterceptor
    }
})

csapp.config(function(){

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('MyHttpInterceptor');

})
```

Comment: How do I set up this Interceptor?

Comment: read on interceptors & setup [here](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Comment: I think something doesn't work. Where is `$q` injected?

Comment: i have given you a stripped down version... sorry will fix it

Comment: I wanted to give you concept rather than exact code, but anyways updated the code to inject $q